# Saving new models using AngularJS and $resource

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get an understanding of AngularJS using $resource, however most of the examples I see out there don't explain how to actually create new instances of something using $resource (or how the entire setup should look).
I've posted my code at the bottom of this.

I have the following setup, where posting to '/entry/api' should create a new entry.
The entry object it self has three properties: name, description and id.

i thought that calling
$scope.save(); would do two things:

1. Map the input fields as POST data
2. make a POST request to the url defined in the $resource (in this case '/entry/api')

Some examples I've seen are manually mapping the data to the resource as such:

```
var entry = new Entry();
entry.name = $name; // defined in entryController
entry.description = $scope.description; // <-- defined in entryController
entry.$save()
```

I thought this wasn't supposed to be necessary, as these fields are defined in the html.
This solution results in:

1. Defining a model in the backend
2. Defining a model in the front end (the entryController `div`)
3. Adding the values from the from the entryController `div` to the JS version of the model and then finally saving it.

It might be the way AngularJS works, however I thought that the input fields in the html would automatically be mapped.

Otherwise you have at least 3 places in the code to update if you add or remove a property of your (backend) model.

How are you supposed to use AngularJS along with `$resource` to save new objects?

```
angular.module('entryManager', ['ngResource']);

function pollController($scope, $resource) {
    $scope.polls = $resource('/entry/api/:id', {id: '@id'});

    $scope.saveEntry = function() {
        this.save();
    }
}


<html ng-app="entryManager">
... <-- include angularjs, resource etc.

<div ng-controller="entryController">
    <input type='text' ng-model="name"><br/>
    <textarea ng-model="description" required></textarea><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveEntry()">Save</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The first think you should note, that `scope != model`, but scope can contain model(s).

You should have some object in your scope and then save it.

So, there would be something like the following:

#### HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="entryController">
    <input type='text' ng-model="poll.name"><br/>
    <textarea ng-model="poll.description" required></textarea><br/>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="saveEntry()">Save</button>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
function pollController($scope, $resource) {
    var polls = $resource('/entry/api/:id', {id: '@id'});

    $scope.saveEntry = function() {
        polls.save($scope.poll);
    }
}
```

**Note1:** even if you do not have initialized poll object, AngularJS will automatically create new object when you start typing.

**Note2:** its better to wrap your form into `ngForm` (by adding `ng-form="someformname"` attribute to div with ng-controller or wrap with `<form name='...'>..</form>`. In this case you could check validity of form by `$scope.someformname.$valid` before saving.

Good example is on main page of AngularJS web site under "wiring the backend" section (btw, mine favorite).

Comment: Useful answer but I don't like the saveEntry method because it is clunky and not object oriented. Angular's resource object creates nice 'proxies' that have their own $save method and it would be cleaner to use that throughout. You can create a new instance of the resource with 'new' as per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) and have neater, cleaner code as a result.

Comment: It is not very resonable to call resource.$save from markup, because trere are many scenarios you need do something after you saved the entity data represented with $resource object - show a toast for error and/or success, navigate user to the related entities list, or do something else what requires usage of a callback. Do you want write whole callback function in the ng-submit attribute? Even if you will write something like ng-submit="model.$save(saveSuccessCallback, saveFailureCallback)" this is not so nice to expose into markup how your JS is organized or other JS-level "internals".

Comment: `scope != model`? The docs disagree: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-as-data-model

Answer (score 4):

Don't use save method over model object itself, use save method of model class, For example -

```
//inject User resource here
$scope.user = new User();

$scope.user.name = "etc";

User.save($scope.user,function(response){

});
```

previously i was using `$scope.user.$save(function(response){})` it was clearing my $scope.user object